# Error correction alogrithms that are effective yet easy to code

Tags: algorithm, encoding, error-correction

I got interested when I frequently got annoyed about DVDs becoming unreadable. The simple method is to write two copies, but I am interested in something more sophisticated.

I came across [fountain codes](http://blog.notdot.net/2012/01/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Fountain-Codes), you need just enough distinct segments that **add up to the size of the data**. Thus I can store n DVDs worth in n+1 DVDS, which is arbitary scaling.

---

I want to implement a backup algorithm/method for fun.

**Question**: What are some encoding algorithms that:

1. can be used to generate backups (uses redundant data to withstand failure of one part)
2. are easy to understand and code (I want to try it out)
3. allows arbitary redundancy (the part about "n DVDs worth in n+1 DVDS")

Comment: don't DVDs already contain error-correction codes? I can't recall the last time I burnt a DVD and it 'became' unreadable....Perhaps there is a problem with your burner or blank DVDs?

Comment: It not relevant to the discussion, but some DVDs randomly fail after some weeks :-)

Comment: mine don't. and I believe it is relevant.

Comment: Two copies alone suffer from a problem, you need to know which of the two different copies is correct and which is not. Sometimes minor data corruptions or omissions are OK as the data can be approximated using the available data before and/or after the problematic place, but it depends on the nature of data and application at hand.

Comment: @MitchWheat: I used to own a few CDs (that I'd burned on my PC) which sat on a shelf for some 3 or 5 years in my room and became unreadable in that amount of time. The material degraded over time. How about that?

Comment: Yes. That has happened to me. Bur not for quite a few years. I have many CD's sat on the shelf for more than 8 years. BUT never after just a few weeks. That symptom sounds like a faulty batch of DVDs or a faulty burner.

Answer (score 1):

While generated out of specific curiosity - this is a very broad subject itself. Perhaps there are two subjects that party try to solve the same problem.

**1. Error correction/detection coding**
If you are annoyed from BAD Data sectors from DVD, but imagine what happens when you are cell phone, the problem of dealing with errors is extremely difficult. There are many algorithms that allows various type of protections such as [CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) methods, [FEC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_error_correction) algorithms etc. and many flavors of them for various domains.

**2. Redundancy algorithms for storage**
The storage to become reliable more than the inherent reliability of disks. There is a very well established framework of RAID based systems which (see [this](http://www.storagesearch.com/tandberg-raidn-art.html)) keeps just enough additional information that allows to retrieve information in case of disk failures.

The core for both such algorithms are based on checksum information that provides mechanisms of to detect and correct errors.

This answer is quite elementary because your question wasn't specific about any particular method. However, if need more help you can research these subject and post more.